# How to capture radio box values in Django?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, radio-button

I am working on a Django project. I am not able to capture radio button values. What I want is this - if out of three answers(three radio buttons with values a, b, c respectively, the user selects say b, then in the answers table, out of the three answers columns, the second column should capture 'b' and nothing (meaning blank) should be stored in the other two columns. Quite obviously the "nm" I have written in request.POST as of now is wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.

The form code is as below

```
  <input type="radio" id = "ans1" name = "nm" value = "a" class = "form-control">{{question.ans1}}
  <input type="radio" id = "ans2" name = "nm" value = "b" class ="form-control">{{question.ans2}}
  <input type="radio" id = "ans3" name = "nm" value = "c" class ="form-control">{{question.ans3}}         
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

In the views file the function is as below

```
  def updateans(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
     user_id = request.POST['user_id']
     questionid = request.POST['questionid']
     ans1 = request.POST['nm']
     ans2 = request.POST['nm']
     ans3 = request.POST['nm']
     myans = Answers(questionid_id = questionid, userid_id = user_id, ans1 = ans1, ans2=ans2, ans3=ans3)
     myans.save()
```

Comment: You should use a form. Without it, you're not validating any of the user input. Also your `name` attributes need to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.get()` method to set a default if no value is returned. This will add an empty string to the DB if the selection is left empty. (assuming `blank=True`)

```
  def updateans(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
     user_id = request.POST['user_id']
     questionid = request.POST['questionid']
     ans1 = 'a' if request.POST.get('nm') == 'a' else ''
     ans2 = 'b' if request.POST.get('nm') == 'b' else ''
     ans3 = 'c' if request.POST.get('nm') == 'c' else ''
     myans = Answers(questionid_id = questionid, userid_id = user_id, ans1 = ans1, ans2=ans2, ans3=ans3)
     myans.save()
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this did not fully work. I chose the option 'b' but I see 'b' put in all the three answer columns in the database table instead of just showing in the second column. I also checked the table and blank=True for all answer columns.

Comment: Just edited my answer to do what you are looking for. Not sure if you have a specific reason for structuring your DB this way, but you might want to use a single `CharField` with A, B and C as choices instead of having 3 separate fields.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. The code now works. Actually if I want Q and A both in one table and also keep only one ANS column (as you suggested) then it would mean multiple rows for every question (because of multiple choice answers). The other way is to keep questions in one table and the answers in another but for this, I would want a master-detail relationship in Django admin and I do not know how to do this. In Django admin I would want to enter question in the Q table and the multiple answers as rows in the ANS table (child table) -  id key of the Q table would be foreign key in the ANS table.